# how to position a div to the very right side of the screen

Tags: html, css

this is a very basic task concerning css. I'm trying to place a search bar to the very right corner of the screen but, When ever I add/reduce padding to the div, the search bar remains in the same place but the screen size increases horizontally. Here is the code to better understand:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>cats</title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form class="form_style">
        <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search me..." required>
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Search">
    </form>

    <div id="top_menu"> 
      <ul>
        <li><a href="suomeksi.php">Suomeksi</a></li>
        <li><a href="log_in.php">Log in</a></li>
        <li><a href="sign_in.php">Sign in</a></li>

     </ul>

    </div>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

    #top_menu {

        height: 35px;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 8px;
            }

    #top_menu li { 
        display: inline; 
        padding: 20px; 
            }

    #top_menu a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #00F;
        padding: 1px 1px 1px ;
            }

    .form_style {
        width:500px;
        margin:50px ;
        position: absolute;

        left: 80%;
        top:-40px;
            }

    .search {
        padding:8px 15px;
        background:rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
        border:0px solid #dbdbdb;
            }

    .button {
        position:relative;
        padding:6px 15px;

        left:-5px;
        border:2px solid #207cca;
        background-color:#207cca;
        color:#fafafa;
            }

    .button:hover {
        background-color:#fafafa;
        color:#207cca;
            }


    </style>


    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the screen capture

[image]

Comment: add float: right; on the element (form_style i believe)

Comment: for an absolute positioned element `right: 0px` will do.

Comment: this didn't do the trick

Comment: did you remove `left: 80%`?

Comment: here what i have now:  .form_style {
        width:500px;
        margin:50px ;
        position: absolute;
       
        float:left;
            }

Comment: the width is making you believe something wrong, remove it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
.form_style {
    width:500px;
    margin:50px ;
    float:right;
    top:-40px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try it

```
.form_style 
    {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

it should work

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS for the right-aligned element should contain `right:0`

Maybe you also need to remove the width and margin definitions

```
.form_style {
    /* width: 500px;*/
    /* margin: 50px; */
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it works. The thing is that you 500px form_style is sticked to the right and 250px are empty and seems to be space

Answer (score 0):

Try this......

```
    .form_style {
      position: relative;
      margin-top:-18px;
      float:right;
      right:-18px;
      top:0px;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Paul, and welcome to StackOverflow. This answer has been flagged for review due to its length. On SO we try to discourage code-only answers, preferring some explanation of the solution to accompany the code. Please read [answer]

Answer (score 0):

First at all you need to remove the margin value for the form style, then position to the right not with the `left` value and align the content:

```
.form_style {
    width:500px;
    margin:50px ;     //Make this 0;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;          //Add Right and remove left
    top:0;            //Make this 0;
    text-align:right; //Align the elements inside form to the right
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ka46wb6/)**